# I've been tasked with finding out why our once successful outlook signature script is now throwing an "Invalid Outside Procedure Error" Please advise

Tags: outlook, vbscript, adsutil.vbs

When I try to run this code I get an error message that states: `invalid outside procedure`.
Is there an issue with my format; is it too dated?
I do not know how to proceed.

```
On Error Resume Next
Const RTF = "6"
Const Text = "4"
Const HTML = "8"

'Declare:
Dim qQuery, objSysInfo, objuser
Dim FullName, PhoneNumber, MobileNumber, FaxNumber, Department
Dim web_address, FolderLocation, HTMFileString, StreetAddress
Dim County, Company, Country
Dim UserDataPath, mail
Dim cert, vet

'Check AD:
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
objSysInfo.RefreshSchemaCache
qQuery = "LDAP://" & objSysInfo.Username
Set objuser = GetObject(qQuery)

'Retrieve:
SPACE = ""
cert = 0
vet = 0
```

Comment: You did not declare the `Space` variable @ITMan1818.

Comment: `Space` is actually the name of a built-in VBScript function and likely a reserved word.